# Inserting 0 in a list for a specific condition in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `J` and a numpy array `inv_r`. I want to obtain a new list `inv_r2` based on `J` as shown below but whenever `J[0][0]` appears, I want `0` to be inserted. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

inv_r2=[]
J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
index=[[]]

inv_r=np.array([[19436.34013609, 20118.9577258 , 20606.73993168, 19471.35381891,
    20144.97489348, 19518.70812614, 20685.76698401, 20032.65982561,
    19694.87399016, 20191.66204251, 20289.75387733, 19436.34013609]])

for i in range(0,len(J[len(index)-1])):
    inv_r1=inv_r[0][J[len(index)-1][i]]
    inv_r2.append(inv_r1)
print(inv_r2)
```

The current output is

```
[19436.34013609, 20606.73993168, 19436.34013609, 20685.76698401, 20032.65982561, 20191.66204251, 20289.75387733]
```

The expected output is

```
[0.0, 20606.73993168, 0.0, 20685.76698401, 20032.65982561, 20191.66204251, 20289.75387733]
```

Comment: "whenever J[0][0] appears": do you mean, when that specific value appears in `J[0]`? Because `J[0][0]` only appears once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a loop, use numpy's methods:

```
j = np.array(J[0])

out = np.r_[0, inv_r.ravel()][np.where(j==j[0], 0, j+1)]
```

Output:

```
array([    0.        , 20606.73993168,     0.        , 20685.76698401,
       20032.65982561, 20191.66204251, 20289.75387733])
```

Comment: How can I convert the output you show to a list as I show in the expected output?

Comment: You mean a list? `out.tolist()`